# Error: conflicting types for 'primeiraPessoa'

Tags: c

Fiz uma função onde passo como argumento dois inteiros e dois ponteiros de duas struct que eu criei com o objetivo de escrever o return num ficheiro txt.
Ao executar o programa, se eu der `printf()` ao return da função no `main` dá o valor pretendido, mas se no `fprintf()` já não dá esse valor. Como posso resolver?

```
char* primeiraPessoa(int countV, int countF, Visitante *visitante, Funcionario *funcionario){
int hora=0;
char *id;
id = "N/A";
for(int i=0;i<countV;i++){

    if(i==0){

        sprintf(id, "%d", visitante[i].id);
        hora=visitante[i].horaE;

    }else if(hora>visitante[i].horaE){
        sprintf(id, "%d", visitante[i].id);
        hora=visitante[i].horaE;

    }else if(hora==visitante[i].horaE){
        strcat(id,",");
        char idTemp[5];
        sprintf(idTemp, "%d", visitante[i].id);
        strcat(id,idTemp);
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<countF;i++){

    if(hora>funcionario[i].horaE){

        sprintf(id, "%d", funcionario[i].id);
        hora=visitante[i].horaE;

    }else if(hora==funcionario[i].horaE){

        strcat(id,",");
        char idTemp[5];
        sprintf(idTemp, "%d", funcionario[i].id);
        strcat(id,idTemp);

    }
}

return id;
}
```

Para escrever no ficheiro txt tenho a função:

```
void escreveFicheiro(Visitante *visitante,Funcionario *funcionario,int countV,int countF,int countInvalidas,int countBarradas){
char nome [] = "estatisticas.txt";
FILE * fp = fopen(nome, "w");

if (fp) {
    fprintf(fp,"15 - %s\n",primeiraPessoa(countV,countF,visitante,funcionario));
}
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Quais os tipos do que foi passado ao `primeiraPessoa` dentro do `fprintf` ? Coloque também essa parte no código para ficar mais claro

Comment: Coloquei lá a função onde é chamada a  primeiraPessoa e onde estão os tipos das variaveis

Comment: A assinatura da função começa com 2 `ints`, mas está a chama-la com `int`, `Visitante*`

Comment: Peço desculpa, alterei a pouco isso e esqueci de mudar aqui tambem. Mas o erro continuou a dar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse `strcat(id,",");` vai te dar problemas. 4 bytes serão alocados para `id` para o texto `"N/A"` e o terminador nulo. Ao fazer isso você vai estourar a área de memória do `id` e começar a corromper a memória do seu programa.

Além disso, `id` é alocado na pilha. Ao retornar um ponteiro de algo que está alocado na pilha, o resultado é que você tem um ponteiro para uma área de memória não alocada, pronta para ser sobreescrita arbitrariamente por alguma outra coisa.

O que você quer parece que é montar uma string com todos os ids de visitantes e funcionários que tenham uma hora maior ou igual a do visitante ou funcionário anterior ou `N/A` se não houver nenhum.

Considerando que `int` vai de -2147483648 até 2147483647, mas você não está interessado no lado negativo, então você precisará de 10 caracteres/bytes no pior caso para guardar um valor `int`. Somando a vírgula para separá-los e o terminador nulo do último, são 11 caracteres/bytes para cada. No pior caso, você vai colocar os ids de todos os funcionários e visitantes.

Ter uma função separada para fazer a concatenação acaba sendo bem mais simples do que fazer tudo isso dentro da função `primeiraPessoa`.

Então, você pode fazer isso:

```
void concatenar_id(char *c, int id) {
    char temp[11];
    sprintf(temp, "%d", visitante[i].id);
    if (c[0] == 'N') {
        strcpy(c, temp);
    } else {
        strcat(c, ",");
        strcat(c, temp);
    }
}

char* primeiraPessoa(int countV, int countF, Visitante *visitante, Funcionario *funcionario) {
    int hora = 0;
    char *ids = (char *) malloc(11 * (countV + countF));
    strcpy(ids, "N/A");

    for (int i = 0; i < countV; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || hora >= visitante[i].horaE) {
            concatenar_id(ids, visitante[i].id);
            hora = visitante[i].horaE;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countF; i++) {
        if (hora >= funcionario[i].horaE) {
            concatenar_id(ids, funcionario[i].id);
            hora = funcionario[i].horaE;
        }
    }

    return ids;
}
```

Na sua função `escreveFicheiro`, você deve liberar a memória alocada com `malloc`:

```
void escreveFicheiro(Visitante *visitante, Funcionario *funcionario, int countV, int countF, int countInvalidas, int countBarradas) {
    char nome[] = "estatisticas.txt";
    FILE * fp = fopen(nome, "w");

    if (fp) {
        char *ids = primeiraPessoa(countV, countF, visitante, funcionario);
        fprintf(fp, "15 - %s\n", ids);
        free(ids);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Nessa última função, você não está usando os parâmetros `countInvalidas` e `countBarradas`.

Comment: Obrigado! Já apliquei isso no meu programa, mas fiquei com o mesmo problema

Comment: @RodrigoMarcelino Edite a pergunta e coloque a mensagem de erro inteira. Esse *Conflicting Type for 'function'* dá a entender que o erro está em outro lugar.

Comment: A unica coisa que está escrita no erro é: "Error: conflicting types for "primeiraPessoa'. E por o que pode perceber na minha pesquisa na net, esse erro deve-se aos argumentos da função primeiraPessoa, só que não estou a conseguir resolver

Comment: @RodrigoMarcelino A função `primeiraPessoa` está antes ou depois da função `escreveFicheiro`? Deveria estar antes.

Comment: está depois... Deveria estar antes né? Eu vou fazer isso

Comment: OBRIGADO!!! Era isso! A função tem de estar antes da função onde dou o fprintf(); esta parte do codigo foi feita por um colega meu e não sei como não me lembrei disso.....